# Read a number from a certain line in a text file

Tags: c#, string, io, int

What I want to do is read each line of a text file individually and first find a certain string, and if that string is found read the integer in that line.

Here is how the strings look:

```
{
"SmartCursorToggle": true,
"MapEnabled": true,
"InvasionBarMode": 2,
"AutoSave": true,
"AutoPause": false,
"Language": 1,
"PlacementPreview": true,
"GoreVisualsAllowed": true,
"VolumeSound": 1.0,
"VolumeAmbient": 0.75,
"VolumeMusic": 0.75,
"KeyUp": "W",
"KeyDown": "S",
"KeyLeft": "A",
"KeyRight": "D",
"KeyJump": "Space",
"KeyThrowItem": "T",
"KeyInventory": "Escape",
"KeyQuickHeal": "H",
"KeyQuickMana": "J",
"KeyQuickBuff": "B",
"KeyUseHook": "E",
"KeyAutoSelect": "LeftShift",
"KeySmartCursor": "LeftControl",
"KeyMount": "R",
"KeyMapStyle": "Tab",
"KeyFullscreenMap": "M",
"KeyMapZoomIn": "Add",
"KeyMapZoomOut": "Subtract",
"KeyMapAlphaUp": "PageUp",
"KeyMapAlphaDown": "PageDown",
"Fullscreen": false,
"WindowMaximized": false,
"DisplayWidth": 800,
"DisplayHeight": 704,
"GraphicsQuality": 0,
"BackgroundEnabled": true,
"FrameSkip": true,
"LightingMode": 0,
"LightingThreads": 0,
"MouseColorR": 252,
"MouseColorG": 233,
"MouseColorB": 221,
"Parallax": 90.0,
"ShowItemText": true,
"LastLaunchedVersion": 155,
"ClientUUID": "7d49a838-d7db-4e74-8124-92552a429491642949429491609524294916095159563f7c",
"UseSmartCursorForCommonBlocks": false,
"UseSmartAxeAfterSmartPickaxe": false,
"UseSmartWallReplacement": true,
"DisableLeftShiftTrashCan": false,
"HighlightNewItems": true,
"HidePasswords": false,
"ThickMouseEdges": true,
"ThickMouseEdgesPackedColor": 4289397106,
"ReverseUpDownForArmorSetBonuses": false,
"CloudSavingDefault": false
}
```

Those "{" Brackets are in the text file.

Let's say I want to find the mouse color's R value, I would put each line into a string array and see if the string at index(i) contains "MouseColorR", how would I get the integer in that line??

Comment: You can use Regex for finding it

Comment: How would I go about doing that>

Comment: you only want to access MouseColorR's value?

Comment: Is this just a part of a json file?

Comment: You could use the excellent JSON.NET library to parse this JSON data. E.g. create a class with the properties you need to extract and use the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method.

Comment: Where can i find the JSON.NET library??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stefan mentioned the best way for doing that is using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(str);
var value = json.MouseColorR;
```

`str` is your json input string.

The Data class:

```
public class Data
{
    public bool SmartCursorToggle { get; set; }
    public bool MapEnabled { get; set; }
    public int InvasionBarMode { get; set; }
    public bool AutoSave { get; set; }
    public bool AutoPause { get; set; }
    public int Language { get; set; }
    public bool PlacementPreview { get; set; }
    public bool GoreVisualsAllowed { get; set; }
    public float VolumeSound { get; set; }
    public float VolumeAmbient { get; set; }
    public float VolumeMusic { get; set; }
    public string KeyUp { get; set; }
    public string KeyDown { get; set; }
    public string KeyLeft { get; set; }
    public string KeyRight { get; set; }
    public string KeyJump { get; set; }
    public string KeyThrowItem { get; set; }
    public string KeyInventory { get; set; }
    public string KeyQuickHeal { get; set; }
    public string KeyQuickMana { get; set; }
    public string KeyQuickBuff { get; set; }
    public string KeyUseHook { get; set; }
    public string KeyAutoSelect { get; set; }
    public string KeySmartCursor { get; set; }
    public string KeyMount { get; set; }
    public string KeyMapStyle { get; set; }
    public string KeyFullscreenMap { get; set; }
    public string KeyMapZoomIn { get; set; }
    public string KeyMapZoomOut { get; set; }
    public string KeyMapAlphaUp { get; set; }
    public string KeyMapAlphaDown { get; set; }
    public bool Fullscreen { get; set; }
    public bool WindowMaximized { get; set; }
    public int DisplayWidth { get; set; }
    public int DisplayHeight { get; set; }
    public int GraphicsQuality { get; set; }
    public bool BackgroundEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool FrameSkip { get; set; }
    public int LightingMode { get; set; }
    public int LightingThreads { get; set; }
    public int MouseColorR { get; set; }
    public int MouseColorG { get; set; }
    public int MouseColorB { get; set; }
    public float Parallax { get; set; }
    public bool ShowItemText { get; set; }
    public int LastLaunchedVersion { get; set; }
    public string ClientUUID { get; set; }
    public bool UseSmartCursorForCommonBlocks { get; set; }
    public bool UseSmartAxeAfterSmartPickaxe { get; set; }
    public bool UseSmartWallReplacement { get; set; }
    public bool DisableLeftShiftTrashCan { get; set; }
    public bool HighlightNewItems { get; set; }
    public bool HidePasswords { get; set; }
    public bool ThickMouseEdges { get; set; }
    public long ThickMouseEdgesPackedColor { get; set; }
    public bool ReverseUpDownForArmorSetBonuses { get; set; }
    public bool CloudSavingDefault { get; set; }
}
```

Also if you don't want to use JSON.NET, and you only want that value you can use Regex:

```
var regex = new Regex("'MouseColorR': (\\d{3})");
Match match = regex.Match(str);
if (match.Success)
{
    string v = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: How do Then save the values to the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dynamic` to access a known attribute in any JSON object. Supposing that you are using JSON.NET as mentioned in other answers and comments, and text file name containing the Json object is stored in variable `fileName`, the code would be like:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
var value = json.MouseColorR
```